# How do I theme a Spree website?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

I'm creating a spree e-commerce site and was wondering with the current updates to spree how to theme the default pages ( product, home page ) since I can't seem to find the files to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create the views for the frontend. First understand the idea of how default views are shown.

The default views are located in spree-frontend gem. Check this out.

> https://github.com/spree/spree/tree/master/frontend/app/views/spree

If you want to change the theme for only some parts, add the views for those parts only. If you want to change everthing, add all the views here.

For example, if you want to change the layout and the home page only, for layout you create

> app/views/spree/layouts/spree_application.html.erb

and write your own layout.

for home page you add your html and template to the file

> app/views/spree/home/index.html.erb

similarly you can change all the templates for the pages you want. That is how you change the theme.

---

Note:
you cannot find the files for the views because, the are located in the gem file.

---

## Update I

To avoid having assets from gems, you can edit **vendor/assets/javascripts/spree/frontend/all.js** and vendor **/assets/stylesheets/spree/frontend/all.css**

for example to remove the default assets for spree_static_content you can remove the line

> *= require spree/frontend/spree_static_content

Similarly you can also override the entire css and js, or partially

To replace an entire stylesheet as provided by Spree you simply need to create a file with the same name and save it to the corresponding path within your application’s or extension’s vendor/assets/stylesheets directory.

For example, to replace spree/frontend/all.css you would save the replacement to your_app/vendor/assets/stylesheets/spree/frontend/all.css.

This same method can also be used to override stylesheets provided by third-party extensions.

Its explained very well in details in:
[spreecommerce' documentation](http://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/asset.html)

If you have any confusion with you, please comment and i can help you.

Comment: is there any way to avoid having related assets in vendor/spree/frontend/... ? Requiring tree from all.css for my main application doesnt work. Probably I should add my application.css to spree_application.html.erb ?

Comment: I have added update 1 to the solution. I believe it answers your question.